# Which of the following represents the steps needed to produce crystals from a solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

From a solution of zinc sulfate, we have excess zinc in a solution and need to form pure crystals.

**Possible methods:**
A- Filter, concentrate the solution, evaporate to crystallization point.
B- Filter, evaporate to crystallization point, distill.

**My thoughts:**
In choice A, how can we concentrate the solution (without heating it) if there already is some excess zinc? And in choice B, the last step (distillation), do they mean that we will heat the mixture of crystals and un-crystallized solution so the solution will evaporate and we will be left with the crystals? Wouldn't that remove some of the water of crystallization of the crystals too?

Comment: You could concentrate without heating, depending on the solvent. Apply vacuum maybe? It doesn't really matter, you just need to decide which set of options gives you the pure product. In option B, you would have to consider what happens to any impurities. If you work that out, it should help with your decision.